# 'Type Not Defined' Error After Adding x:Name Attribute To User Control Declaration Inside A User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am having trouble with the Xaml passer throwing a 'Type Not Defined' exception after I add a x:Name attribute to a user control declaration which is inside another user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="LoginView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PowderKegSoftware.Artisan.Client.Authentication"
         xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:PowderKegSoftware.Artisan.Client.Ui.Controls;assembly=CommunalUi"
         xmlns:auth="clr-namespace:PowderKegSoftware.Artisan.Client.Authentication"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:LoginViewmodel,
                                          IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
         d:DesignHeight="693" d:DesignWidth="1080">


<UserControl.Resources>
 ---------------------
</UserControl.Resources>

------------------------

<Border BorderThickness="0">
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage}"
                    Stretch="None" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Text="{Binding UsernameLabelText}"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyle}"/>

            <ctrl:ArtisanComboBox Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="2"
                                  Height="30"
                                  TabIndex="10"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ArtisanComboBoxDefaultStyle}"
                                  DataContext="{Binding UsernamesVm}" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="3"
                       Text="{Binding PasswordLabelText}"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyle}"
                       Margin="0 20 0 0"/>

  ------------------
```

This all works just fine until I try and add the `x:Name` attribute to the `<ctrl:ArtisanComboBox ...` declaration.

```
<ctrl:ArtisanComboBox Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      x:Name="ChoosableUserNames" <!-- Throws a 'Type Not Defined' error. -->
                      Height="30"
                      TabIndex="10"
                      Style="{StaticResource ArtisanComboBoxDefaultStyle}"
                      DataContext="{Binding UsernamesVm}" />
```

I have tried using `x:Name=` and just `Name=` but neither complies. I want to name this declaration so I can use `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ChoosableUserNames}` to set the focus on this control when the view is renered.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f264b70-8f03-4adf-8ff6-24b1d7032dbf/using-xname-on-custom-control-causes-build-to-fail?forum=wpf

Comment: @user2250152 Thank you very much, from the post you referenced I was able to fix my problem. Thanks again.